# Initalizing parameters in a struct in Swift

Tags: ios, swift

So while learning Swift, I came across two ways to initialize parameters in a struct,

```
struct Fruit {
  let name: String
}

let _ = Fruit(name: "Apple")
```

or,

```
struct Fruit {
  let name: String

  init(name: String) {
    self.name = name
  }
}

let _ = Fruit(name: "Apple")
```

What is the difference between two or maybe which one is correct?

Comment: Both forms are identical. In a struct (unlike a class) you get the *memberwise initializer* for free. The explicit declaration is redundant.

Answer (score 2):

-> For structure, we don't need to write initializer explicitly (init) as it is already included by default if attributes are not optional.

-> For classes, we have to define initializer explicitly.

-> 1st option is correct when it comes to structures.

-> if you don't want to take parameters as compulsory while creating an object of structure you can make attributes options like this

```
struct Sample {
   var x: Int?
}
```

-> For more information regarding structures and classes you can follow this link :- https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/ClassesAndStructures.html

Comment: This is incorrect. For classes you have to explicitly state the initializer, for structs it is automatically synthesised , however you can have an initializer for structs and there is nothing wrong with that. In fact you will have to create an initializer for a struct if it is contained in a separate module due to the fact that the synthesised initializer is marked internal.

Comment: is it ok now..?

Comment: If the struct is in another module, the generated initializer is not always accessible.

Comment: struct a {
    var x:Int
    var y: b
}

struct b {
    var z:Int
}. 
var ab = a(x: 1, y: b(z: 3))